Signal analysis - FRF(input+output signal) vs FFT(output signal)
In order to estimate the natural frequencies of a structure, one can do an impact testing that generally requires recording input and output signals.
While calculating the Frequency Response Function (FRF) is the standard approach for determining the natural frequencies of a structure when you have access to both the input (impact hammer) and output (accelerometers) signals. One may not have access to the input signal.
In that case, I believe it's also possible to estimate the natural frequencies by only performing a FFT of the output signal.
From my understanding, FRF is important to provide a test quality check by looking at the coherence of the signal, in order to know if a problem as occured during the test. But one could directly check the results by looking at the FFT of the output signal. If it's not too noisy, then the test was good.
Am I missing something ?

Just to clarify, the transfer function (FRF) and a coherence spectrum are two completely different things. A transfer function characterizes how an input signal is transformed to an output signal after being passed through an LTI system. A coherence spectrum measures the degree of linear correlation between two signals as a function of frequency. Like you said originally, the transfer function estimates the frequency response of the system the input signal is being passed through, not the "coherence of the signal".

Roughly speaking the transfer function (FRF) is the ratio of the output spectrum to the input spectrum, i.e.
$$\text{FRF}(z) = \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)} \tag{1}$$
where $X(z)$ is the discrete Fourier Transform (DFT) of the input and $y(z)$ is the DFT of the output.
If you only have the output spectrum, you need to make assumption about the input spectrum. An impact excitation is very impulsive so as a first order approximation it's probably ok to assume that the input spectrum has a reasonably flat magnitude.
In this case it's probably safe to just use the output spectrum to determine the location of the resonance frequencies although drawing conclusions about the amplitude might be less warranted.
If your system is reasonably stationary, there is very simple way to check the quality of your measurement without having access to the input: Just determine the output spectrum without any excitation. That will give the noise floor of your measurement system. When you do the actual measurement you can compare it to the noise floor. Any frequency range where the measured signal is sufficiently above the noise floor is probably good.

Thanks for you answer, just to be sure that I have understood : do you mean that if we are interested in structure's natural frequency value, then spotting spikes in the FFT of the output signal is enough to obtain correct results. How can we evaluate the uncertainty ? Does that make sense to perform several times the test and take the mean / std values to measure the statistics ?

I am afraid that without knowing the input signal, you can not be sure of the excitation that has been performed (an impulse for example). And therefore obtain wrong frequency values (shift or distorted spectrum) in case of double hit, an impact that lasted for too long, overload ..
